# URL getting coded strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am building a site that allows users to make modifications to some text. I am then building a url so they can come back and their mods will be applied when the page loads. This all works except I am getting some 'funky' characters when I enter the url into the browser address bar.

The url I am putting in is:

```
http://localhost:8888/PlantTags/index%20copy.php/temp=lg_oval&cn=Common Name&cX=-10&cY=40&cf=Giddyup&cfs=52&clh=1&ca=center&bn=Botanical Name&bX=80&bY=115&bf=Comic-Sans-Ms&bfs=21&blh=1&ba=center&rev=false
```

But the browser is coding it to:

```
http://localhost:8888/PlantTags/index%20copy.php?temp=lg_oval&cn=Big%2520Jumbo&cX=-10&cY=40&cf=Giddyup&cfs=52&clh=1&ca=center&bn=Botanical%2520Name&bX=80&bY=115&bf=Comic-Sans-Ms&bfs=21&blh=1&ba=center&rev=false?temp=lg_oval&cn=Big%20Jumbo&cX=-10&cY=40&cf=Giddyup&cfs=52&clh=1&ca=center&bn=Botanical%20Name&bX=80&bY=115&bf=Comic-Sans-Ms&bfs=21&blh=1&ba=center&rev=false
```

So when I grab the cn parameter from the url I am getting extra characters. Can someone tell me where the %2520 is coming from and what to do about it? I have tried inserting it into a textarea and getting the html from that and decodeURIComponent...both failed. Oh yeah....javascript or jQuery is the chosen language.

Thank you again,

Todd

Comment: %20 = " "
%25 = "%"
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: That's what happens when an URL is urlencoded twice !

Comment: @Zeta I know but he has index%20copy  And later on "Botanical%2520Name"

Answer (score 4):

Try not to use spaces in the URL you are trying to encode, but use hyphens. They will be much more readable and will not get encoded in things like `%20` or **double encoded** in `%2520`.

Comment: Double-encoding needs to be fixed, not hidden.

Comment: Yep...some parts are getting double encoded...which would get worse the more times it is copied and reentered. Thanks...

Comment: It could be fixed, but it is impossible to fix it by not seeing his code. So this is a viable solution: why try to fix a problem when you can get rid of the problem altogether?
If it would be necessary to have spaces in the URL (which I think is hardly the case) then we could work on fixing.

Comment: I will be using encodeURIComponent() more...because the user will most likely be entering spaces in their text...so when I build the custom url I will use encodeURIComponent('Common name') for instance...

Answer (score 2):

If you decode `%2520` you get `%20`. You are encoding some fragments twice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, spaces are not allowed as spaces in URL's, and there is a space in "&cn=Common Name"

A browser will change (Actually URL-encode) all spaces to %20 to send the request. So you need to either change the value in something like "common_name" or something, but your server should also be able to handle that... Another way is to Decode the URL server-side so the %20 get turned back into spaces again and then let it do it's thing

Comment: Oh and indeed, %25 is the percentage sign... so "" -> encode -> "%20" -> encode -> "%2520"